# Can I run an Android emulator (with GUI) on a headless Linux server?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, remote-access, virtualization

I have a hosted server that runs the Ubuntu server, and I was wondering if there was a way to run Android applications and get access to the Android GUI remotely, such as with a remote desktop. Also, is there a way to set up this without installing a complete GUI on the remote server to preserve resources?

Comment: Have not used but aware of: [AOSP- Cuttlefish Virtual Android Devices](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/cuttlefish)

Answer (score 0):

It's commercial, but Canonical's [AnBox Cloud](https://anbox-cloud.io/) should be able to do what you need. It runs Android in containers and is intended for streaming Android games, but that is not its only use.

I looked at it for on-premises software testing, because I had test data that I wasn't willing to put on a cloud platform, and Canonical reckoned that could be done.